# Espresso 2.2.1 exception :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

In my app I want to Espresso in order to test the UI. However,when I try to run my project,I get message:

```
  Error:Execution failed for task    
  ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:   
  com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:    
  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
  com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
  org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program 
  Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

This is my gradle setup:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "theo.testing.androidespresso"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'

  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
  core:2.2.1')     
  {
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
}
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'

 }
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure, that it's your third post and it has the same problem.
You're  trying to use dependencies which you don't need to have during the test.

Change your `build.gradle` dependencies section to:

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'

  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
    // Necessary to avoid version conflicts
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}

}
```

Google's official `Android Testing Support Library` site is enough to start Android testing.

See [Espresso](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/index.html) secton

Hope it will help